# How to import ExoPlayer to Android Studio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer

I am very new to coding in Java/Android Studio so please bare with me.I am trying to run demo app in Exoplayer provided on github(https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer). I tried to following steps:

```
-imported the project to android studio 2.2 by File=>Navigate to directory containing exoplayer

-Tools=>Android=>Sync Project with gradle files
-press run button and i get this error:
```

error:

```
 Error running playbacktests: Default Activity not found
```

Could any one help me fix this error and run the demo exoplayer application successfully on android studio 2.2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the Gradle version (build.gradle that's at the root not inside app folder) like this :

```
 dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . I tried what you suggested and re sync and now i get this error :Error:Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in f:\Projects\ExoPlayer-release-v2\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
<a href="fixGradleVersionInWrapper">Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project</a><br><a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a> . How to fix it ?

Comment: Finally by pressing "Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project" the second error went away and i selected demo from run drop-down menu and project run on simulator successfully!

Comment: then have a noce coding :)